# JSP Struts to Velocity Struts conversion

Tags: java, jsp, struts, velocity, csb

I'm asking this on behalf of one of my students - "Does anybody have an idea how to convert JSP Struts to Velocity Struts?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, **you don't have to do it all at once**.  That's pretty important - you should only convert pages as you have time to test them or you will get some degree of a bad result.  Personally, I don't generally do this, preferring Velocity for email templating only.

You have to map the VelocityView servlet (in web.xml):

```
<!-- Define Velocity template compiler -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.velocity.toolbox</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.velocity.properties</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/velocity.properties</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<!-- Map *.vm files to Velocity -->
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You will also need to create the *toolbox.xml* file and put in any tools you want to add and create the *velocity.properties*, which isn't very different from other instances of this file.

**See the [VelocityStruts page](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/struts/userguide.html) and for overview and the [VelocityView page](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/view/index.html#Installation) for how to configure the Velocity servlet.**